# Wrong \ref in genealogytree when used node turns

Tags: hyperref, positioning, genealogytree

When I used the node turn feature of genealogytree any \ref{} inside the nodes text. If i remove the line `node={ turn=right},` it will work correctly. But I need it, any way to do it while the nodes are turned?

Example of the problem: 
[image]

My code:

```
        \documentclass{report}

        \usepackage{genealogytree}

        \usepackage{hyperref}
        \usepackage{pdflscape}

        \begin{document}

            \chapter{Sample chapter}
            \section{Sample section} \label{sectionA}

        %       \begin{landscape}
                \begin{figure}[b]
        %           \noindent\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
                        \begin{genealogypicture}[
                            processing=database,database format=full,
                            info separators={\tcbline}{\tcbline}{}{},
                            node size=3cm,level size=3cm,
                            mark/.style={box={colback=red!20}},
                            requirement/.style={box={colback=green!20}},
                            edges={foreground={line width=1pt,black,->,},background={line width=2pt,white}, }, %swing,
                            box={fit basedim=8pt,boxsep=5pt,segmentation style=solid,halign=center,valign=center,before upper=\parskip2pt,\gtrDBsex,{colback=gray!20}},%halign=center
                            node={ turn=right}, % when this is used
                            ]
                            child{
                                g{name={\textbf{Test}}}                                             
                                child{
                                    g{name={\textbf{Application Based}}, comment= {Test}}
                                        child{
                                            g{name={\textbf{Test}}, comment= {See Section \ref{sectionA} }}                             
                                            }
                                        child{
                                            g{name={\textbf{Test2}}, comment= {See Section \ref{sectionA} }}                                
                                        }
                                    }
                                }                       
                        \end{genealogypicture}
        %           }
                \end{figure}        
        %   \end{landscape}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: Well, it looks like that there is a mismatch in layers, and a hyperlink is difficult to rotate, as far as I know

Comment: You could use cross-references, but just don't link them. I suspect that's the most practical option.

Comment: @cfr how can i do this for just these link not the whole document?

Comment: @Sari Replace `\ref` by `\ref*` -- this suppresses the linking